# Use LINQ to filter dataset for distinct rows based on only one of two columns

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, dataset

I have another newbie LINQ question.

I have a dataset with two columns.

I want to use LINQ to filter the dataset to essentially get the distinct values of column B (ignoring column A). It sounds like group by is more efficient with distinct, so I would be okay with using group by.

Would someone be able to provide some sample code?

Thanks!!!

Comment: How are you going to resolve multiple values of A for the same B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataSet ds = FetchDataSet();

IEnumerable<DataRow> rows =
    from row in ds.AsEnumerable()
    group row by row.GetField<string>("columnB") into g
    select g.First();
```